# Булевы вычитания в Unity3d. Поиск готового решения

Tags: unity3d, геометрия

Нужно производить булевы вычитания.
Исходные финуры: кубы (либо простейшая объёмная буква "Т"), плоскости (до 10 углов, в т.ч. невыпуклые). Полигонаж минимальный для таких фигур.
Вычитания производятся в реалтайме. С одним мешем может быть 6-8 последовательных вычитаний.

Простые примеры использования:

1) Есть помещение с шестью стенами и плоскость пола. Нужно подрезать эту плоскость по стенам, чтобы получился пол правильной формы.

2) Есть керамическая плитка на стене. Её нужно подрезать по границе стены и по границе дверного проёма одновременно. Если плитка на полу -- подрезать просто по границе пола (пол может быть невыпуклым многоугольником, плитка в результате может быть разделена на две части).

Сейчас используется данный плагин: https://github.com/karl-/pb_CSG
К сожалению, иногда он вешает приложение без отладочной информации и даёт артефакты.
Сам я с вычислениями не дружу, писать что-то своё тяжело.

Может кто-то посоветовать другие решения?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать юнити как 3д редактор не имееет смысла. **Юнити это игровой движок, а не 3д редактор.** Обьекты которые можно создавать в юнити по факту нужны только для тестов.

Решение более чем простое: для моделирования нужно использовать 3д редактор на ваше усмотрение: 3дс макс, майя либо любой другой.

Comment: Вычитания производятся в Play Mode. Более того, в сборке.

Comment: Снова таки, это не рентабельно с точки зрения ресурсов. Все разбивание и разрушение обьектов делается в первую очередь в 3д редакторе, а потом уже обьекты помещаются в одну кучу как цельный. Делать это во время игры = неоптимально использовать ресурсы конечного пользователя. Точно то же самое относится к булевым вычетаниям в моделях.

Comment: Никто не говорил, что это реализация разрушений. Это неигровой софт со специфическими задачами. И то, и другое явно следует из первоначальной постановки задачи. Всё содержимое сцены создаётся процедурно, поэтому подготовить необходимые вещи заранее нельзя. Нет никакого обозримого множества вариантов вычитания объектов.